# Convert sslsocket python code to ruby

Tags: python, ruby, sockets, ssl

I have such code on python connect to some software by socket:

```
import socket, ssl

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8963
sert_key = '../keys/key.pem'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, True)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, True)
sock.settimeout(30.5)
sock.connect((host, port))
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True, certfile=sert_key,
ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)


cert = "hello"

cert = cert.encode('utf-8')
req = ('%08x'%len(cert))+cert
sock.sendall(req)
print sock.recv(4096)
```

Output: "OK", so its work.

I try to convert such code on ruby, but it doesn't work:

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8963
sert_key = '../keys/key.pem'

socket = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)
address = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, host)
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, true)
socket.connect(address)

#socket = TCPSocket.new(host, port) # not help also

ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new(:TLSv1)
ssl_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open(sert_key))
ssl_context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open(sert_key))
ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, ssl_context)
ssl_socket.sync_close = true
ssl_socket.connect


sert = "hello"                                                                                                                                                                                            
sert = sert.force_encoding('UTF-8')                                                                                                                                                                        
req = sprintf("%08x", sert.length) + sert                                                                                                                                                                  
ssl_socket.write(req)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
puts ssl_socket.read(4096)
```

But I have such error:

test1.rb:30:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello B: bad message type (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Help me please port this code on ruby. I don't understand what I miss (where difference in codes).

P.S. Sorry, but software to which I want to connect not for sharing for now :(

Comment: The difference is that TCP-wise, you are a client connecting to a server. TLS/SSL-wise, you seem to act as the server-side of the connection. This is defined in your Python code by passing `server_side=True` to the function `ssl.wrap_socket`. In the Ruby code, you simply connect to the server as though you were an TLS client. I am not sure about a solution to this right now, but I will add an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: How's your key.pem structured - are you sure there's a key and a certificate in there?

Comment: @emboss: The Python side would probably not work if this weren't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should use something like this:

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8963
sert_key = '../keys/key.pem'

socket = TCPSocket.new(host, port) # not help also

ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new(:TLSv1)
ssl_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open(sert_key))
ssl_context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open(sert_key))
ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, ssl_context)
ssl_socket.sync_close = true
ssl_socket.accept

sert = "hello"                                                                                                                                                                                            
sert = sert.force_encoding('UTF-8')                                                                                                                                                                        
req = sprintf("%08x", sert.length) + sert                                                                                                                                                                  
ssl_socket.write(req)
puts ssl_socket.sysread(4096)
```

**EDIT:** Updated code yet another time.

Comment: Yep, this help, but now execution freeze on line:
    puts ssl_socket.read(4096)

Maybe invalid method to send by ssl_socket.write(req) - in python used "sock.sendall(req)"

Then I stop software, I have in output in ruby string "OK" - what I want :)

Comment: `ssl_socket.read(4096)` tries to read 4096 bytes and ONLY returns either if all those bytes are received or the socket is closed. You can either close the socket first (`ssl_socket.close; puts ssl_socket.read`) OR use `ssl_socket.recv` instead of `ssl_socket.read` OR use non-blocking IO with `select`. I updated the code to use the second method.

Comment: undefined method `recv' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket:0x10802b878> (NoMethodError) - I already try :(

Comment: Okay, you want to use one of the other two options then. Updated the code to use method 1, which might not be what you want but is the easiest way.

Comment: openssl/buffering.rb:36:in `sysread': closed stream (IOError)
 from /openssl/buffering.rb:36:in `fill_rbuff'
 from /openssl/buffering.rb:68:in `read'
 from test.rb:23:in `<main>'

This is if I close socket before. Maybe in someone way use returned socket from ssl_socket.accept?
By doc this method return another socket, but i try write and read from this socket and also mix with current socket (read and write) - the same workaround.

Comment: "By doc", this does not return another socket, but self (we are looking at `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket#accept` here, maybe you looked at `SSLServer#accept`). Try using the select approach or call read_nonblock in a loop until it returns non-nil (but please avoid a busy loop, so at least add a sleep(0.01) or something). I updated the code and also tested it out, so it probably works now (finally :)

Comment: Thanks, but not work :(

until data = begin 
  ssl_socket.read_nonblock(4096)
rescue => e 
  puts "Error #{e.inspect}"
  nil
end
  sleep 0.01
end
puts data


Error #<NoMethodError: undefined method `read_nonblock' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket:0x10756f1c8>>
Error #<NoMethodError: undefined method `read_nonblock' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket:0x10756f1c8>>
Error #<NoMethodError: undefined method `read_nonblock' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket:0x10756f1c8>>

SSLSocket very strange.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? In Ruby 1.9, this works. In Ruby 1.8.7, you can use `ssl_socket.sysread(4096)` without any further tricks (this also works in Ruby 1.9, as I now realize). Updated the code accordingly. This seems to be the best match for your Python code.

Comment: Yaaaaa!! Thanks. Sorry, forgot switch rvm to 1.9.2. Big thanks!